# Proof by induction with the Union of sets

Tags: probability, statistics, induction

Proof by induction:

$$ P( \cup _{i=1}^n A_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i) - \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 \leq n} P(A_{i_1} \cap A _{i2} ) + \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 <i_3 \leq n} P(A_{i1} \cap A_{i2} \cap A_{i3}) -...+(-1)^{n+1}P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n)$$

I don't really understand the whole i1

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inclusion-Exclusion_Principle

Comment: for two sets it is obvious $P\left( A\cup B \right) =P\left( A \right) +P\left( B \right) -P\left( A\cap B \right) $

Comment: What is $P$? My first association was power set, which doesn't fit here.

Comment: @MvG I would assume $P$robability.

Answer (score 1):

For three sets (events), it is intuitively clear why the formula works: If we  take the measure (probability) of the union then we count the pairwise intersections twice. So we subtract the measure (probability) of the intersections. But then we subtracted  the measure (probability) of the triple intersection. So we have to add it.

[image]

If there are more sets (events) then you can argue the similar way. We added the measure of the pairwise intersections twice. So subtract them. But then we subtracted the measure (probability) of the triple intersections. So let's add them. But now we added the measure of the four-tuples of intersections. So subtract them...